# What is the music playing in One Piece episode 644 when Hajrudin encounters Lucy aka Luffy?

Tags: one-piece, music

What is the music playing in One Piece episode 644 when Hajrudin encounters Lucy aka Luffy?

Comment: Why are people voting to close this as "unclear"? I don't watch One Piece, but the question seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: Ask @Alagaros He is the first one to vote in the voting history. Dimitri mx and Matt were the others. The fourth vote is strangely not recorded in the history list though. Am I right to assume the first voter is not recorded in the closing history list?

Comment: @senshin At the time I voted so as there was no specific time given yet. Making it a pretty broad question. Seems to have been edited since, and retracted my vote

Comment: @senshin I was the one who added the timestamp into the question. I use my own interpretation of the question ("when Hajrudin encounters Lucy") and pinpoint at the timestamp 20:40 when Lucy/Luffy charges Usy towards Hajrudin but fails to take him down. It turns out there was another soundtrack after it, showing Lucy/Luffy standing against Hajrudin, which I missed when I made the edit. I have rolled back my changes, and the question is indeed **unclear**.

Answer (score 2):

The song which starts playing at 22:00 and continuing on to the scene where Lucy/Luffy stands back up and faces Hajrudin is **ルフィ猛攻!** (*Luffy's Fierce Attack!*) from the album [*ONE PIECE THE MOVIE Norowareta Seiken Soundtrack*](http://vgmdb.net/album/44982).

The song can be sampled on [Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.jp/gp/product/B00AGKEFQY/ref=dm_ws_sp_ps_dp) and [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oLdFWj4R5zo).

Comment: I don't think so. The music in Luffy's Fierce Attack! has lots of high tom (?) and tambourine, but the music in the part in the question has short roll on snare drum.

Comment: Sorry yesterday, Karthick wasn't saying which minute he was talking about. And I thought it's about the fight when Luffy fights back Harjudin.
Also don't give -1, like that before reading the question of the user when he posted it and how he posted it. and how I replied It was unclear what he was saying.

Comment: I apologize for jumping to conclusion. I didn't watch to the end of the episode, where there is another scene which can be called "encounter". I'll revert the change in the question and restore the votes.

Answer (score 1):

The soundtrack playing at 20:40 (when Lucy/Luffy charges Usy towards Hajrudin but fails to take him down) is Track 26 **ゴムゴムが効かない?!** (*Gomu Gomu Is Ineffective?!*) in the album [*ONE PIECE "Adventure in Nejimaki Island" Music File*](http://vgmdb.net/album/42756).

You can listen to a sample of the track on [Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.jp/gp/product/B00AG4BSYW/ref=dm_ws_sp_ps_dp) or [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oBbdo4ivbmQ&t=7m43s).